# Woocommerce Coupon Menu and Marketing Menu missing After "Coupons can now be managed from Marketing > Coupons."

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

Today while working on woocommerce site, I have found this notification from WooCommerce(screenshot Attached).

[image]

When I hit "Remove legacy coupon menu" button, it removes WooCommerce->menu from the dashboard but there is no Marketing(main menu) was found(as referrenced here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/).

WC Version: 4.5.2

I have also tried to downgrade the version of WooCommerce but it doesn't work either(as suggested here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/coupons-now-is-under-marketing-and-coupon-box-on-checkout-is-gone/#post-13148335)

Do someone know how to bring back Coupon menu under Woocommerce or atleast to new Marketing(main) Menu for WooCommerce.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to bring back Legacy WooCommerce->Coupon menu back.

Go to your database, and go to

> wp_options

table(check prefix of table in your wp-config.php file) and find this

> wc_admin_show_legacy_coupon_menu

under option_name column, set its value from 0 to 1.